# cpplint FATAL ERROR: No files were specified

Tags: c, cpplint

When I type this command in terminal

```
cpplint --filter=-whitespace,-whitespace/braces
```

I get this Error

**FATAL ERROR: No files were specified.**

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You didn't specify any files to check.

Comment: Hint: You have to lint *something*.